# Using if-else statement in a block []

Tags: javascript

I have the following statement:

```
arr.push([student.name,student.id]);
```

I want to add an `if-else` block in this statement so I could add `student.name` only if the `if` is true, something like:

```
arr.push([student.name if (validName(student.name))
         ,student.id]);
```

But this syntax is not valid. Is there a proper way to achieve this idea?

**EDIT**:

My array contains a lot of elements and I want to add to most of them (if not all of them) some kind of check. Something like:

```
    arr.push([student.name if (validName(student.name)),
              student.id   if (validId(student.id) && idContainsNine(student.id)),
              student.avg  if (student.avg !== 'undefined'),
              ...
              ]);
```

I push the values only if the `if` statement is true. If it false, it will not push it. for example if `validName(student.name)` returns false it will not push `student.name` in the array.

Comment: what do you want to add if not valid?

Comment: `if (validName(student.name)){arr.push([student.name,student.id]);}else{if(true){//do what you want}`

Comment: You could use ternary operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: what do you like to take instead of the name? omit this part?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You could take a conditional operator and get only an array with valid values.

```
array.push(validName(student.name)
    ? [student.name, student.id]
    : [student.id]
);
```

---

An other approach is to use functions which return after a check either an array with the value or without.

For using this result, you need to spread the array and if it does not contain any element, it does not increase the length of the array.

```
cost 
    includeName = name => validName(name) ? [name] : [],
    includeId = id => validId(id) && idContainsNine(id) ? [id] : [],
    includeAVG = avg => avg !== 'undefined' ? [avg] : [];

arr.push([
    ...includeName(student.name),
    ...includeId(student.id),
    ...includeAVG(student.avg)
]);
```

---

Another solution could be to use an array of checks and return in case of unwanted items an own `Symbol` (if `undefined` or ``null` is a used value) and filter the array before pushing it to the result set.

```
const
    EMPTY = new Symbol('empty'),
    checkName = ({ name }) => validName(name) ? name : EMPTY,
    checkId = ({ id }) => validId(id) && idContainsNine(id) ? id : EMPTY,
    checkAVG = ({ avg }) => avg !== 'undefined' ? avg : EMPTY;


array.push([checkName, checkId, checkAVG]
    .map(fn => fn(student))
    .filter(v => v !== EMPTY)
);
```

Comment: Not quite what I need because I have a lot of checks like this. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ternary operator.

```js
arr.push([validName(student.name) ? student.name : '', student.id]);
```

Replace empty string value `''` with what you want when you get invalid `student.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one.It may help you.

```
arr.push([student.name,(student.id ? student.id : '')]);
```